# Placing an image at a different spot than the focal length?

Tags: optics, waves, fourier-transform

What would the image look like? Is it just the fourier transform but with a transformation on the axis? I was kind of intuitively interpreting the lens as separating the frequencies, so placing the image plane would result in a change of the axis of original image.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking Given the position of the object from the lens $a$ and the focal length $f$ the image is at $b$, with $1/a + 1/b = 1/f$ by the thin lens formula.

Comment: @my2cts I'm just asking what it would look like if we move the image plane closer and farther

Comment: By moving the object farther  and closer? It may change magnification.

Comment: @my2cts Magnification of what? I thought it would act as transforming the frequency axis.

Comment: Magnification of the image.

Comment: @my2cts but the image would be out of focus